# Simplifying constructing native SQL query with nested if-else's

Tags: java, sql

I've a method which is used to build a native sql query. I've 4 String builder as input and based on different conditions, I need to build my query.

Here is the code

```
private void appendConditions(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder condition, StringBuilder condition2,
    StringBuilder condition3) {
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition.toString())) {
    query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND+"(");
    query.append("( " + condition + " )");
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition2.toString())) {
        query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
        query.append("( " + condition2 + " )");
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition3.toString())) {
            query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
            query.append("( " + condition3 + " )");
        }

    } else {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition3.toString())) {
            query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
            query.append("( " + condition3 + " )");
        }
    }
    query.append(" )");
} else {
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition2.toString())) {
        query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND+"(");
        query.append("( " + condition2 + " )");
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition3.toString())) {
            query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
            query.append("( " + condition3 + " )");
        }
        query.append(" )");
    } else {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition3.toString())) {
            query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND+"(");
            query.append("( " + condition3 + " )");
            query.append(" )");
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I run my Sonar report, it says the Cognitive complexity is higher for this method. Can I simplify this methods avoiding many if-else loops

Comment: Where does `ApplicationConstants.AND` come from?

Comment: Do you have unit tests that exercise this code? This is tangential to the question but for code this complex you NEED unit tests before you start changing it. Since its just building strings it should be easy to unit test.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let's look for some patterns in your code:

First of all, we notice that you have three parameters with similar names. `condition`, `condition2` and `condition3`. These names indicates a code smell, that we should use an array or list instead.

Taking one step at a time, we see this code is repeated multiple times:

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition.toString())) {
    query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND+"(");
    query.append("( " + condition + " )");

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition2.toString())) {
    query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
    query.append("( " + condition2 + " )");

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition3.toString())) {
    query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
    query.append("( " + condition3 + " )");

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition3.toString())) {
    query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
    query.append("( " + condition3 + " )");

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition2.toString())) {
    query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND+"(");
    query.append("( " + condition2 + " )");

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition3.toString())) {
    query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
    query.append("( " + condition3 + " )");

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition3.toString())) {
    query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND+"(");
    query.append("( " + condition3 + " )");
```

This indicates that we can extract a method. (We can also notice that the `"("` should be added for the *first true* if-statement, this is important but we will ignore this for now and get back to this later).

```
private boolean addParameter(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder condition) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition.toString())) {
        query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
        query.append("( " + condition + " )");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void appendConditions(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder condition, StringBuilder condition2,
    StringBuilder condition3) {
if (addParameter(condition)) {
    if (addParameter(condition2)) {
        if (addParameter(condition3)) {
            // we don't actually care about the result here
        }
    } else {
        if (addParameter(condition3)) {
            // not here either
        }
    }
    query.append(" )");
} else {
    if (addParameter(condition2)) {
        if (addParameter(condition3)) {
            // again, don't care about result
        }
        query.append(" )");
    } else {
        if (addParameter(condition3)) {
            // yeah ok, here we actually care...
            query.append(" )");
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's pretty clear that `query.append(" )");` should always be done last, so that can be moved out and then we can avoid some `if` statements.

```
private void appendConditions(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder condition, StringBuilder condition2,
    StringBuilder condition3) {
if (addParameter(condition)) {
    if (addParameter(condition2)) {
        addParameter(condition3);
    } else {
        addParameter(condition3);
    }
} else {
    if (addParameter(condition2)) {
        addParameter(condition3);
    } else {
        addParameter(condition3);
    }
}
query.append(" )");
```

And now we're doing the same in both some if's and else's, so that can be simplified:

```
private void appendConditions(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder condition, StringBuilder condition2,
    StringBuilder condition3) {
if (addParameter(condition)) {
    addParameter(condition2);
    addParameter(condition3);
} else {
    addParameter(condition2);
    addParameter(condition3);
}
query.append(" )");
```

Once again we're doing the same thing:

```
private void appendConditions(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder condition, StringBuilder condition2,
    StringBuilder condition3) {
addParameter(condition);
addParameter(condition2);
addParameter(condition3);
query.append(" )");
```

So we're essentially doing the same thing three times. This is where a loop would be handy.

```
private void appendConditions(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder... conditions) {
    for (StringBuilder condition : conditions) {
        addParameter(condition);
    }
    query.append(" )");
```

And now of course, we don't really need that separate `addParameter` method.

```
private void appendConditions(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder... conditions) {
    for (StringBuilder condition : conditions) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition.toString())) {
            query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
            query.append("( " + condition + " )");
        }
    }
    query.append(" )");
```

---

Now, let's get back to the parenthesis: `+"("` is added in the first true if-statement in your original code. So this, in connection with the closing `" )"` can be handled by for example keeping a `boolean` to check for if an if-statement has been true so far.

```
private void appendConditions(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder... conditions) {
    boolean conditionUsed = false;
    for (StringBuilder condition : conditions) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(condition.toString())) {
            query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
            if (!conditionUsed) {
                conditionUsed = true;
                query.append(" (");
            }
            query.append("( " + condition + " )");
        }
    }
    if (conditionUsed) {
        query.append(" )");
    }
```

But when reflecting more about what it is that you do, we see that you have a collection of `StringBuilder`s, you check each if it is not empty, then you join them together with `ApplicationConstants.AND`.

```
    String specialConditions = Arrays.stream(conditions)
        .map(StringBuilder::toString)
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(ApplicationConstants.AND));
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(specialConditions)) {
        query.append(" (");
        query.append(specialConditions);
        query.append(" )");
    }
```

Voilà!

Answer (score 8):

A very short review;

- Escape your parameters with [escapeSql](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String)), this is so important!
- You should pass the conditions in array, so that the call can pass an arbitrary amount of conditions
- `ApplicationConstants.AND` <- total overkill, just use `AND`

Comment: Going down the SQL path, I'd argue that parameterized queries is even better than escaping the parameters.

Comment: Call me OCD crazy, but I do both (escape, then pass to a parameterized query.)

Heck, when I get my way, I put everything in stored procedures (DMLs and DML templates are never exposed in code, nor in config files), called with CallableStatements and with parameters already escaped.

It's extra work to set up, but it has saved me countless hours in maintaining and trouble shooting.

Comment: @luis.espinal escape and then parameterize? If this means what I think it means the end effect will be that you're storing an SQL-escaped version of the data in the database, which is an absolute nightmare to anyone trying to maintain it after you

Comment: This is only a concern if the data has questionable "injections". A string with "John Doe" can be sql-escaped ad infinitum yielding "John Doe."

I do this when I have to interface with teams or software that might take values I send and concatenate them into SQL statements (rather than using binding variables.)

I've had more headaches by cowboys that do that than by doing what I've just described.

YMMV, depending on how *you* (the generic *you*) codes and what kind of teams you must interact with.

Comment: This should probably go to chat, but using parameterized queries *and* escaping is just bad practice, in all cases.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't follow this approach at all, trying to create a dynamic SQL by hand using StringBuilder or StringBuffer.

It is inevitable that the complexity will shoot off the roof. And it is very rare to find a need for building SQL statements dynamically like that.

In 30 years, I haven't seen a justification. Every application I've known has a finite set of access patterns, ergo a finite set of SQL statements it needs.

Instead, I would suggest you use parameterized SQL statements (see example below from [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html))

```
String sql = "update people set firstname=? , lastname=? where id=?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
        connection.prepareStatement(sql);

preparedStatement.setString(1, "Gary"); 
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Larson"); 
preparedStatement.setLong  (3, 123);

int rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Better yet, load that string from a resource bundle or property.

Other possibilities include using a DSL like [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) (example below, from the jOOQ's site):

```
create.select(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, count())
      .from(AUTHOR)
      .join(BOOK).on(AUTHOR.ID.equal(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID))
      .where(BOOK.LANGUAGE.eq("DE"))
      .and(BOOK.PUBLISHED.gt(date("2008-01-01")))
      .groupBy(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
      .having(count().gt卌)
      .orderBy(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME.asc().nullsFirst())
      .limit(2)
      .offset(1)
```

Or [QueryDSL](http://blog.mysema.com/2011/01/querying-in-sql-with-querydsl.html) (example below):

```
QCustomer customer = new QCustomer("c"); // alias for the CUSTOMER table

SQLTemplates dialect = new HSQLDBTemplates(); // SQL-dialect
SQLQuery query = new SQLQueryImpl(connection, dialect); 
List<String> lastNames = query.from(customer)
    .where(customer.firstName.eq("Bob"))
    .list(customer.lastName);
```

Or, if you are using JPA, to use the JPA's [Criteria API](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-criteria-api-in-expressions) (example below):

```
Subquery<Department> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Department.class);
Root<Department> dept = subquery.from(Department.class);
subquery.select(dept)
  .distinct(true)
  .where(criteriaBuilder.like(dept.get("name"), "%" + searchKey + "%"));

criteriaQuery.select(emp)
  .where(criteriaBuilder.in(emp.get("department")).value(subquery));
```

Good luck.

Comment: So much this. If you absolutely need to build a query at runtime, use something like the Criteria API with for example Hibernate

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but after reading through the code I have following thoughts:

1. Why do you use `StringUtils.isNotEmpty` instead of `.isEmpty()`? It looks fairly unlikely that `condition.toString()` would return `null`. Also, for `StringBuilder` you may want to use length (`condition.length != 0`)
2. Since if's logic for different `conditions` is almost identical, you can use a loop:

```java
private void appendConditions(StringBuilder query, StringBuilder... conditions) {
  StringBuilder subQuery = new StringBuilder();
  for (StringBuilder condition: conditions) {
    if (condition.length != 0) {
      if (subQuery.length != 0) {
        query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND);
      }
      subQuery.append("( " + condition + " )");
    }
  if (subQuery.length != 0) {
    query.append(ApplicationConstants.AND+"("+subQuery+")");
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: `!= ""` should not be used when comparing strings. It would compare the *object reference* instead of the actual *content*.

Comment: @SimonForsberg sure, stupid me. It should have been .isEmpty(). Fixed!